# How to invert a masked numpy array?

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I've created a mask over a vector shapefile and have then created another one which zooms in to the relevant area. The problem I have with this new mask is that the masked area is the bit that I want, so I need to invert it somehow. (*Note that I imported numpy as np*)

**This is the code I used for the 2nd mask:**

```
catchment_mask = gmask[minrow:minrow+nrow, mincol:mincol+ncol]
catchment_mask = np.where(catchment_mask == 1, 1., np.nan)
```

I've tried using this code to invert it but it has applied a mask to the entire area:

```
inverse_catchment_mask = (np.logical_not(catchment_mask))
```

I'd be really grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: Your indentation is off.  There is a `np.ma`, MaskedArray subclass, but I don't think that's what you have.  It looks like your `mask` is a slice of `gmask`, but then you make a new array using `where`.  Why?  That's no longer a `view`.  Why the `np.nan`?  `logical_not` of that is `False`.

Answer (score 1):

If your `cachement_mask` consisted of boolean (True/False) values, then you solution based on `logical_not` would work as expected

But your mask consists of `1` or `NaN`, so you have to invert this more carefully. For example:

```
inverse_cachement_mask = np.where(np.isnan(cachement_mask), 1, np.nan)
```

This will create an inverse of your original mask, swapping the `1` and `NaN` values.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I removed the np.where and changed it for logical_not with the relevant arguments and it has inverted it as expected with boolean values.